# VLC - Subtitle Background ( Padding )

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

I would like to increase width of 'Subtitle Background,' because I have eye issues and I struggle to read subtitles.

You can see in the following image what I want to do:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adjusting the subtitle settings in the Preferences window? I am using an old VLC, but my preferences window looks like this.

[image]

You can see where I've circled. You can increase the text size of the subtitles, and adjust the "outline thickness". Playing around with mine, I can get the subtitles to a very large size, and they become clearly legible.

Comment: You might also want to try a serif font; they can be easier to read. There's also a font called Open Dyslexic which has very good cues for the eye to differentiate. It's a little odd-looking, but not too strange & does seems to be very 'fast' on the eye.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I am looking for subtitle background width that how can I increase it's width.